# Create Flexbox grid with same height on content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a Flexbox grid where the images have the same height and the margin(gutter) adjusts itself depending on the size of the image.

I have tried to set the images to a certain height, but when text is added, the text does not break according to the width of the image.

https://www.o-p.se/work

As seen in my examples below I found a way to set a masonry grid without text. But when I add text the text block creates a white space besides the image.

This is what I want it to look like:
[image]

This is how it looks without text:
[image]

And this is my issue:
[image]

This is my set up.

```
<div class=”collection-list”>

<div class=”collection-item”>
<img src=”url” class=”image”>
<div class=”text-block”>Image text</div>
</div>

<div class=”collection-item”>
<img src=”url” class=”image”>
<div class=”text-block”>Image text</div>
</div>

<div class=”collection-item”>
<img src=”url” class=”image”>
<div class=”text-block”>Image text</div>
</div>

<div class=”collection-item”>
<img src=”url” class=”image”>
<div class=”text-block”>Image text</div>
</div>

</div>



.collection-list {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: flex-start;
}

.collection-item {
display: flex;
height: 10vw;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
}

.image {
height: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Can you try to do a minimal reproduction of what you tried ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If I understood correctly you want all the items in the grid to have the same height? Can you please clarify what exactly is your problem here?

Comment: here you should find everything you need about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: there are some important points to consider here. set parent display to flex and set min-width for images

Comment: @Coolis I want the text to break according to the image so the images aligned both on the left and the right side.

Comment: @Mad7Dragon whit a min-width on the images they become to big.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

So after seeing your photos, I believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

```css
.collection-item-28 {
  margin-bottom: 14px; /* Adjust this to your liking */
}
.text-block-19{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Preview:
[image]
Smaller:
[image]

Comment: Tried that, but the images doesn't keep their proportions, they squeeze.

Comment: @RASALGHUL I updated my answer, check it and let me know.

Answer (score -1):

From what I have understood the thing that you need. I have created a small sandbox implementation for that. You can check just the index.css file and App.js to look for structure.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-roman-4dv820

Let me know if it helps or you need any clarification or a thing apart from that.

Cheers :)

Comment: In your example the images have different heights unfortunately.

Comment: Answers must be self-contained. The solution needs to be _here_. Please see [answer].